# How can I store a shared_ptr dynamically in a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I got a class called `BuildingPlan` which is holding different values and functions. For minimal code I just use one function `step()`, which iterates the `stepCount`.
I also got a class called `Builder` which holds building plans for different objects (like garage and house) as shared pointers.
Now I want to call the right `step()` function by choice of the user.

I assume that I need to use a pointer for my problem. But when I run the following minimal code the values of `stepCount` are not changed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class BuildingPlan {
 public:
  BuildingPlan(int stepCount) : stepCount(stepCount) {};
  int stepCount;
  bool step() {
    std::cout << "Building plan is now in step " << stepCount << std::endl;
    return true;
  };
};

class Builder {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<BuildingPlan> house{new BuildingPlan(0)};
  std::shared_ptr<BuildingPlan> garage{new BuildingPlan(0)};

  std::shared_ptr<BuildingPlan> whatToBuild;
};

int main() {
  Builder builder;
  bool finished = false;

  while (!finished) {

    // now i want to change which shared pointer is used
    int id;
    std::cout << "What do you want to build? (0 = house, 1 = garage, 2 = finish) ";
    std::cin >> id;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    switch (id) {
      case 0: {
        builder.whatToBuild = builder.house;
        break;
      }
      case 1: {
        builder.whatToBuild = builder.garage;
        break;
      }
      case 2:
        finished = true;
        break;
      default:
        std::cout << "Wrong number!" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    builder.whatToBuild->step();

    std::cout << "House step: " << builder.house->stepCount << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Garage step: " << builder.garage->stepCount << std::endl << std::endl;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

I expect that the `stepCount` increases when I call the function `builder.whatToBuild->step()`
Could you please lead me to the right direction in how to use the pointer/shared_ptr properly?

Comment: You never change stepCount. Why do you think it has to increase?

Comment: Look closely at `std::cout << "Building plan is now in step " << stepCount << std::endl;` and explain to yourself where `stepCount` increases.

Comment: Ah $#%@... Thanks so much. I searched for the misbehavior in the shared_ptr and did not check my functions. Thanks so much!